# Replacing strings in a PowerShell file and then calling it via batch + command line arguments

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

This is my PowerShell file:

```
#Replace.ps1

    Param(
       [string]$filepath,
       [string]$find,
       [string]$replace
     )

    $content = Get-Content  $filepath

    $content = $content.replace($find,$replace)

    $content | out-file $filepath
```

This is the batch file which I am using it to call this

```
#ChangeIP.bat
@echo on
powershell.exe -File E:\Replace.ps1 %1 %2 %3
```

Now when I try to call the batch file from cmd as:

```
ChangeIP.bat  "E:\foreign logs.txt" firstword secondword
```

then it is showing some ridiculous errors.

I basically am stuck in passing the file name (which is having white spaces).

The code I need basically should be able to do the following things:

1. A PowerShell script that takes three command line arguments:

   - FilePath       // With white spaces (don't know how)
   - String to replace
   - String to be replaced with
2. The PowerShell script should be able to fetch the contents of the "FilePath" supplied. Find the "String to replace" string and Replace it with "String to be replaced with" string
3. Then calling this PowerShell script via batch file and supplying the three command line arguments there.

**Please keep in the mind, the file path contains spaces.**

Comment: Why are you using a batch file to call a powershell script? Why not just call the powershell script directly?

Comment: "*then it is showing some ridiculous errors.*" - they're probably meaningful errors. Please edit your post and include them.

Comment: `powershell.exe -File "E:\Replace.ps1" "%~1" "%~2" "%~3"`?

Comment: @aschipfl let alone the batch file, even if i pass the filepath with spaces in powershell, it is showing, "Replace method not found..."

Answer (score 0):

Try the `-replace` operator instead of the `Replace()` method in case you're starting PowerShell v2:

```
$content = $content -replace $find $replace
```